# Index not re-organised

Tags: sql-server, index, ola-hallengren

I am using Ola's INDEX Maintenance solution. Few indexes are not being re-organised after running job.Below is my code

```
    EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize
    @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
    @FragmentationLow = NULL,
    @FragmentationMedium = 
   'INDEX_REORGANIZE,INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
   @FragmentationHigh = 'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
   @FragmentationLevel1 = 5,
   @FragmentationLevel2 = 30,
   @UpdateStatistics = 'ALL',
   @OnlyModifiedStatistics = 'Y',
   @LogToTable = 'Y',
   @PageCountLevel = 0
```

Few indexes which has fragmentation level 27 % still doesn't get re-organised even after running Index-optimize job.

I have went through frequently asked questions, it suggests about pagecountlevel which is already 0 in my case.

Also it has index_id =1 rather than 0.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that these indexes are very small.

[Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand) comments [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/94121/60085)

> Ola's solution is set to ignore indexes with less than 1000 pages (see
>   the @PageCountLevel parameter). You can override that so that it cares
>   about indexes with fewer than 1000 pages, but why? Wasted effort IMHO.
>
> I would stop worrying about small tables like this - let Ola's
>   solution do its job, and worry about fragmentation when you can
>   actually prove it is causing a tangible performance problem for a
>   specific index. "Fragmentation is high" is not a problem on its own.

Additonally, [Thomas Stringer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2241/thomas-stringer) comments [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/18373/60085)

> If an index is very small (I believe less than 8 pages) it will use
>   mixed extents. Therefore, it'll appear as if there is still
>   fragmentation remaining, as the housing extent will contain pages from
>   multiple indexes.
>
> Because of this, and also the fact that in such a small index that
>   fragmentation is typically negligable, you really should only be
>   rebuilding indexes with a certain page threshold. It is best practices
>   to rebuild fragmented indexes that are a minimum of **1000 pages**.

Comment: I just want to identify which indexes that this excludes. Purpose of this I am using this SQL to generate a report to identify which indexes needs to rebuild/re-organize . I use this sql to generate a report https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/All-Databases-Index-a68ed3c5 .

Comment: Run index optimize job from Ola then run the above sql to check whether those indexes are rebuild/reorganized. When i run this I am getting few indexes which suggest me to rebuild/re-organize. I am struggling to write some sql to identify these indexes so that i can exclude from my report or use any parameter in ola's job to rebuild/re-organize

Answer (score 0):

To get an fragmentation level matching Ola's scrips you need to use

```
sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, 'DETAILED')
```

and filter on `index_level=0`

I find the general attitude that unexplained fragmented should be ignored until proven to cause catastrophic issues interesting. It explains some of the experiences we in the application team are having.